# Can I combine troops from multiple regions when conquering?

Tags: small-world

I have a question regarding Smallworld and using tokens to attack a region from multiple regions.

The scenario is this: A group of 7 Shrooms is sat between a group of 2 dwarfs to the north and 6 to the south. Can the dwarfs combine forces to attack the region with the Shrooms?

Answer (score 12):

**No, they cannot combine.** (in the way that you are implying).

Attacks are not made from units on the board, they are made from units "in hand".  Once deployed to the board, units may not be moved or picked back up until the next turn.

Each attack is from one distinct region to another.  Note that during the *Ready your Troops* phase, you should pick up all extra troops from each area (and can even eliminate all troops from areas if you wish) in order to make a bigger attack force.

In your example, if those troops haven't attacked this turn, then you can effectively combine them when you ready your troops.